# Sql запрос на поиск как можно реже используемого значения среди строк

Tags: mysql

Имеется база данных, в ней таблица, а в таблице строки, все как обычно.
В таблице есть столбец `time`, тип `Integer`
Нужно узнать наиболее уникальное значение поля time среди всех строк в таблице.
Вот например есть 3 строки в таблице, у двух time равно 2, а у третей равно 3, выходит две строки с time - 2 и одна с time - 3, получается что 3 — наиболее уникальное число(меньше всего используется) среди всех строк, каким SQL запросом можно найти данное число?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT `time`, COUNT(*)
FROM `table`
GROUP BY `time`
ORDER BY 2 ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: А насколько вот хорошая идея сортировать по номеру столбца, а не по его названию? На мой взгляд, это и менее удобно/очевидно при чтении, и больше подвержено ошибкам при изменении запроса.

Comment: _насколько вот хорошая идея сортировать по номеру столбца, а не по его названию?_ Имхо предпочтительна. Например, в данном конкретном запросе использовать имя поля имхо не получится - алиаса у него нет, а использование `ORDER BY 'COUNT(*)'` ещё более сомнительная идея... сорри за обычные тики вместо бэков - косяк форматирования.

Comment: `ORDER BY COUNT(*)` я ни в коем случае не предлагаю. Вполне возможно, что MySQL соптимизирует и высчитает `COUNT` лишь раз, но гадать не хочется. А вот создание alias-a для `COUNT(*)` и его использование в `ORDER BY` кажется мне предпочтительным вариантом, не имеющим вышеуказанных недостатков. И при этом, надо полагать, создание alias-a не ухудшает производительность запроса.

Comment: ``ORDER BY `COUNT(*)` `` - а вот можно и с обратными (это я про форматирование кода в комментариях).

Comment: @Regent Ну наверное это вопрос привычек и пристрастий. Мне сортировка по номеру поля привычна, понятна и даже где-то удобна. К тому же у меня не бывает случаев, когда что-то завязано на порядок полей в результирующем наборе (вот подобную ситуацию как раз считаю недопустимой), а добавление в выходной набор полей я всегда выполняю в конец списка вывода.